# How to prevent installation of an application on the iPad

Tags: build, xcode4, installation, app-store, distribution

How do I build an app in Xcode to prevent it's installation on an iPad? The answers to related questions I see here seem to refer to settings and procedures that no longer apply in Xcode 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this it is not possible to prevent an installation of an app on a certain type of device.

But a cheap and dirty way to prevent iPad users from using the app would be to check in the `appDelegate`:

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
//UIAlertView this app will not run on iPad
}
```

and than in the `UIAlertView` Delegate:

```
exit();
```

This will cause the app to not run on the iPad.

Comment: Thanks; but the question is how to prevent installation in the first place.

Comment: That doesn't exist.  So in lieu, I created this

Comment: Cool. If true, could you edit to that effect? Then I'll mark this as the answer.